what is this symbol called and how can it be rendered in latex
I have attached an image of the symbol below. The author uses it to generally denote any mathematical theory.


This is a particular representation of a “calligraphic” T. There's nothing special in the particular shape. I've see dozens of ways of denoting a generic theory and the present one isn't universal like, say, + or ∫.

thanks for the clarification

I cross posted with various subs on Reddit and found my answer but thanks anyway, this does indeed also resolve it
